# Quick question about signed full adders (carry and overflow)

Tags: digital-logic, verilog

For a 4-bit signed full adder, the output range in decimal is -8 to +7. I created a 4-bit signed full adder in verilog and simulated it. When I added +5 and +3, I got a sum of -8 and overflow=1. This should be correct right? When I added +3 and -1, I got a sum of +2 and a carry of 1. Is this correct or is my code wrong?

Comment: I can't see what you did wrong if you don't post the code lol.

Comment: Is a carry of 1 for +3 and -2 incorrect though? I created a 1 bit FA using structural modeling and then used a generate loop to generate a 4bit full adder.

Comment: Think about what a carry indicates. For instance, in an unsigned 4-bit adder, if I told you that I added 2 + 2 and got 4 + 16 = 20, would that be correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a signed adder the carry out bit has no meaning. Only the overflow bit has meaning and importance.

For +3 + (-1) you get result 2 and no overflow, which is the correct answer

(+5) + (+3) gave you +8 with overflow, also a correct answer